# How to increment a loop in Vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I've got a multi-object array and I'd like to have it loop through a particular group of objects.

This is my code so far

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <h1>My Test App</h1>
    <button v-on:click="getHockeyData">Get Team Data</button>
   <div v-for="hockeyData in hockeyDataList" :key="hockeyData.id" >
     <p>{{ hockeyDataList.teams[0].roster.roster[1].person.fullName }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: "Weather",
  data() {
    return {
      hockeyDataList: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
   getHockeyData() {
      axios.get("https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/21?expand=team.roster").then(response => (this.hockeyDataList = response.data));
    }
  }
  
};


</script>
```

I know the loop won't work in it's current state. The portion of my output within the loop that I need to increment is `roster[1]` - I'm new to Vue so not sure how to use the `v-` commands to increment that 1 until there are no more instances of it.

Any help or feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `v-for` over the others `hockeyDataList.teams` then inside that if you want to loop over `hockeyDataList.teams[0].roster.roster`, then its 2 nested v-for's and so on

Comment: @LawrenceCherone that's the idea! I've got a v-for going already, I need to be able to insert some form of incrementing along my roster object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop over the others, really you want to start from teams as that's the way the JSON is structured

Example using various parts of the JSON, view the file for others.

```
<div v-for="team in hockeyDataList.teams" :key="team.id">
  <h1>{{ team.name }}</h1>
  <div>{{ team.venue.name }}, {{ team.venue.city }}</div>
  <div>Created in: {{ team.firstYearOfPlay }}</div>
  <div>Division: {{ team.division.name }} - Conference: {{ team.conference.name }}</div>

  <h2>Roster</h2>
  <div v-for="player in team.roster.roster" :key="team.id + '-' + player.person.id">
    <h3>{{ player.person.fullName }}</h3>
    <div>
      Number: {{ player.jerseyNumber }} - Position: {{ player.position.name }} {{ player.position.type }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would love to use this one as it shows me how to use so much of the information! I'm getting an error when trying to run this though, "the template root disallows 'v-for' directives"

Comment: Figured it out, excellent answer that provided me with more than I initially asked for and really helped me learn ways of using and incrementing the loops. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
<div v-for="team in hockeyDataList.teams" :key="team.id" >
 <p v-for="roster in team.roster.roster :key="roster.id">
   {{ roster.person.fullName }}
 </p>
</div>
```

It's not necessary, but if you want to, you can get index in a v-for as well:

```
<div v-for="(team, index) in hockeyDataList.teams" :key="team.id" >
 <p>
   {{ hockeyDataList.teams[index].roster.roster[1].person.fullName }}
 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

v-for increments the index automatically for you. The problem is that the api returns a json and not an array we can iterate on. By looking at the api response, we can see that teams is the array we can iterate on.

`<v-for="(team, i) in hockeyDataList.teams" :key="i">`

where index automatically increments until the end of list. We can then iterate through the roster.

`<v-for="(roster, j) in team.roster.roster" :key="j">`

Putting it all together

```
<div v-for="(team, i) in hockeyDataList.teams" :key="i">
  <div v-for="(roster, j) in team.roster.roster" :key="j">
    <p>{{ hockeyDataList.teams[i].roster.roster[j].person.fullName }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```